# VS2015 NuGet Cannot Install Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager or ServiceBus

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I cant install the NuGet packages in my windows universal app.

I thought this might be because the configuration manager is not compatible with windows universal apps, but now I have the same problem for the ServiceBus package.

When I try the install through the NuGet manager it says

> Package Restore Failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App1'.

So I tried to install the Configuration Manager through the package manager console and the error is shown below. I have tried deleting .suo file and restart VS. I have also tried uninstalling NuGet package manager, restarting, reinstall and restart.

I have installed the WindowsAzure.Storage and WindowsAzure.MobileServices without any issue.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager


Restoring packages for 'App1'.
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Diarmaid\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\project.json...
Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Package restore failed for 'App1'.
Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

which azure sdk are you having on your machine? 
I would recommend to update your VS tools with update 1 and latest extensions updates for NuGet manager...etc. then clean your solution. build and re-add any needed packages or restore. let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks @Mostafa. I cant get it working so am trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting UWP?  It does not support Configuration Manager.

You can find alternative solutions here:
Reference: [The "Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager" library is not available for UWP apps. Suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947321/the-microsoft-azure-configuration-manager-library-is-not-available-for-uwp-app/37062027#37062027)

Simply:

```
   var credentials = new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey");
   var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
```